# Images doesn't get updated with computed method NuxtJS + working example

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a bookmark list, & I used local storage to save user choices as a bookmark

after one coin get's added to the bookmark list I sort them based on this event and added coins gets on top of the list

My issue is when I reload the page images & links doesn't get updated base of data change but anything else will

I've created a working example on the code sandbox website

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-chandrasekhar-pt3pm?file=/pages/index.vue

Here is an example on our online website(This is for the advanced trade page):

https://app1.tabachain.com/trade?market=DOGE_USDT

[image]

Comment: Hi, don't post code images but rather actual text please.

Comment: Hi, I've created an online working example this time as u told in my previous question
you can check codes there, the image is more readable here and only for those that want to get what's going on faster

Comment: I removed the snippet so.

Comment: No one has answered me yet, can u help me? I mean I've some ways to solve this but I want someone expert opinion about this too...